# A homework question about permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I was tutoring, and for some reason I could not get the correct answer to this question:

*A licence plate can have 6 characters; 1 letter followed by 5 digits.  In how many ways can a plate me made?*

I tried 26$\cdot\text{P}(10,5)$.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: it's $10^5$ instead of $P(10,5)$, numbers can be repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

License plates with repeated digits (for example, $A00000$) are allowed under the rules you cited. However, $P(10,5)$ only counts the sequences of five digits *where repetition is not allowed*.

See [the Wikipedia page on permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics).

Comment: Ah, so I missed that fact I can repeat numbers.  OK, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer $= 26\cdot 10^5$
Since each of 5 digits can be chosen from $\{0,1,...,9\}$ set in $10$ ways, thus total number of ways $= 26\cdot 10^5$.